# trying to install angular cli and facing error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to install angular cli using the command in ubuntu system.

npm install -g @angular/cli

BUt i am facing the following error:
782 verbose Linux 5.0.0-23-generic
783 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
784 verbose node v10.19.0
785 verbose npm  v6.13.4
786 error code EACCES
787 error syscall access
788 error path /usr/lib/node_modules
789 error errno -13
790 error Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
790 error  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules']
790 error   stack:
790 error    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'',
790 error   errno: -13,
790 error   code: 'EACCES',
790 error   syscall: 'access',
790 error   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
791 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
791 error It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
791 error
791 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
791 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
791 error the command again as root/Administrator.
792 verbose exit [ -13, true ]

Any reason why I am facing this issue?

Comment: `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

`

Comment: Use ```sudo npm install -g @angular/cli``` .. You should install ```cli``` with user persmission for which  it shows the error as ```Error: EACCES: permission denied``` .. So you need to use ```sudo``` infront of the cli command..

Comment: i ran it and faced another error:npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm ERR! dest /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' -> '/usr/bin/ng'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

Comment: Unistall the cli globalli: `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`. Clean the cache: `npm cache clean --force` install the cli globally again: `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi tried and again facing issues:deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm ERR! dest /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' -> '/usr/bin/ng'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

Comment: Which version of nodejs are you using? you can use `node --version` to get it.

Comment: node --version 10.19.0

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Command Prompt as an administrator
and then try installing angular-cli once again